# Delete interceptor from stack in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

In `struts.xml`, I have included `tokenSession` interceptor to my interceptor-stack to validate token for each request. Unfortunately, the same isn't working well for AJAX requests. I got `invalid.token` response when it executes `actionInvocation.invoke()`.

Hence, I would like to stop executing tokenSession interceptor for AJAX requests (alone). I have a custom interceptor (logging) which get invoked prior to `tokenSession` interceptor. Is it possible to delete `tokenSession` interceptor from stack in logging interceptor based on request type (if it is an AJAX request)?

Answer (score 2):

Token interceptor extends `MethodFilterInterceptor` that means that you can exclude execution of interceptor bases on method names.

In your interceptor stack configure it like that:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="token">
   <param name="excludeMethods">your_ajax_methods_comma_separated</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Another solution is to use different interceptor stack for you AJAX actions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different Interceptor Stack for your Action, or use different Interceptor Stacks for different packages, and group all the Actions in the right package.